# org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException: The primary key read from the row during the execution of the query was detected to be null

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, primary-key

I'm trying to query some data on JPA, this is my query:

```
@Override
    public List<HorarioAtencion> findByPeriodo(Person person, int dia, int mes, int anno) {
        Query busqueda = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from HorariosAtencion where " +
                                              "idPerson = ?1 AND "+
                                              "DAY( fechaInicio) <= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaInicio ) <= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaInicio) <= ?4 AND "+
                                              "DAY( fechaFin) >= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaFin ) >= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaFin ) >= ?4 ORDER BY TIME(fechaInicio)", HorarioAtencion.class);
       busqueda.setParameter(1,person.getId());
       busqueda.setParameter(2, dia);
       busqueda.setParameter(3, mes);
       busqueda.setParameter(4, anno);
       return busqueda.getResultList();
    }
```

This query returns results, but the next exception is fired:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
     => 1
     => 13
     => 2013-01-04 12:25:00.0
     => 2013-01-04 12:25:00.0
     => true
     => true
     => true
     => true
     => true
     => true
     => true)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=HorarioAtencion sql="Select * from HorariosAtencion where idPerson = ? AND DAY( fechaInicio) <= ? AND MONTH( fechaInicio ) <= ? AND YEAR( fechaInicio) <= ? AND DAY( fechaFin) >= ? AND MONTH( fechaFin ) >= ? AND YEAR( fechaFin ) >= ? ORDER BY TIME(fechaInicio)")
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Columns definition on entity class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fechaInicio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaInicio;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fechaFin")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaFin;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "domingo")
    private boolean domingo;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "lunes")
    private boolean lunes;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "martes")
    private boolean martes;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "miercoles")
    private boolean miercoles;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "jueves")
    private boolean jueves;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "viernes")
    private boolean viernes;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "sabado")
    private boolean sabado;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idPersona", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Persona idPersona;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What database are you using, and what does it return for the column names?

**EclipseLink** is case sensitive in less recent versions by default unless the `eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names` persistent property is set to true.

This might be the problem for native queries if the database returns the column name as uppercase `"ID"` when you have it defined as lowercase `"id"`.

Try changing the column definitions in the annotations to match what your database uses or adding the property with a value of true.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that eclipselink is case sensitive.  There is a "hint" available that will address this.  Place the following between your properties element in the persistence.xml file:

```
<!-- Hint to solve "The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(...)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null." errors.-->
<property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true"/>
```

That will treate the column names in a case insensitive manner and eliminate the error.

Answer (score 2):

Found this thread https://forums.oracle.com/thread/614380.

Had the same issue with postgres and EclipseLink.

Solution:
Change the primary key column to be upper case that is:

select id **as "ID"**, field1, field2,..., fieldn from table ....

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in `HorariosAtencion` table a `null` value was found in a field which corresponds to the primary key.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer but my table doesn't contains any null value

Comment: @rafuru, hm, its strange: in your query you use field named `idPerson`, but in entity class description your fields is called `idPersona` (see last `a` in the name). Isn't this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

> ...The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(...

Indicates that the `HorariosAtencion` record is fine. There are two IDs, two dates and all the booleans. `1` is probably the the ID value. So, I suspect the exception refers to the *related* `Persona` entity. Are there `Persona`s with null PKs?

Answer (score 0):

It's either there is/are null value on one/more of the primary key of HorariosAtencion 
/Persona.
double check your database.

Or you need to set the persona id instead of referencing the object,
try

```
public List<HorarioAtencion> findByPeriodo(Person person, int dia, int mes, int anno) {
    Query busqueda = em.createQuery("from HorariosAtencion where " +
                                          "idPerson = ?1 AND "+
                                          "DAY( fechaInicio) <= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaInicio ) <= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaInicio) <= ?4 AND "+
                                          "DAY( fechaFin) >= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaFin ) >= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaFin ) >= ?4 ORDER BY TIME(fechaInicio)", HorarioAtencion.class);
   busqueda.setParameter(1,person);
   busqueda.setParameter(2, dia);
   busqueda.setParameter(3, mes);
   busqueda.setParameter(4, anno);
   return busqueda.getResultList();
}
```

or

```
public List<HorarioAtencion> findByPeriodo(Person person, int dia, int mes, int anno) {
    Query busqueda = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from HorariosAtencion where " +
                                          "**idPerson.id** = ?1 AND "+
                                          "DAY( fechaInicio) <= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaInicio ) <= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaInicio) <= ?4 AND "+
                                          "DAY( fechaFin) >= ?2 AND MONTH( fechaFin ) >= ?3 AND YEAR( fechaFin ) >= ?4 ORDER BY TIME(fechaInicio)", HorarioAtencion.class);
   busqueda.setParameter(1,person.getId());
   busqueda.setParameter(2, dia);
   busqueda.setParameter(3, mes);
   busqueda.setParameter(4, anno);
   return busqueda.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and i found a solution, try removing "HorarioAtencion.class from the line em.createNativeQuery.